# does "npm pack" memorize version of package?

Tags: npm, package, version

I'm newbie at development, first, I'm not good at English. I hope your understanding.

---

**TLDR;**

I'm making UI library now. for the test of it, I found `npm pack` command.

It seems like If I enter `npm pack` once in specific version, then I cannot change the library contents without upgrading version in package.json file.

I wanna modify contents of library and test of it without version upgrade before publish.

is this possible?

ex) my situation

1. library v0.0.8, I found some problems.
2. modified contents of library without upgrading version(to v0.0.9)
3. npm pack
4. install library at test folder
5. changes were not reflected in test folder.

[package.json -image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFetK.png)

---

I'm making an npm UI library for company.
I was thinking about how to do the test of it, and found "npm pack" command.

I made the pacakage version v0.0.8, and entered the "npm pack" command.

after copy of tgz file, I pasted it to root directory of test folder.

and I downloaded it with `yarn add ./library-test-0.0.8` at test folder.

after that, I found some problems of library, so modified those at package files.

but I didn't modified version of pacakage as v0.0.9 in package.json file.

after delete all builded files at dist directory, I entered `npm build`, `npm pack`

and I deleted v0.0.8 from my test folder with `yarn remove library-test`

again, after copy of new tgz file, I pasted it to root directory of test folder.

However, the changes I made were not properly reflected at test folder.

I tried `npm cache clean --force`, but it didn't work.

also, I tried it in new test folder, but it was same.

[folder structure -image at ui-library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u25Xa.png)

[folder structure -image at test folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vug7r.png)

as you can see above images, types folder should be deleted.

I guess, if I enter 'npm pack' command once, npm memorize that version and does not change.

is there any way to reset this npm's behavior?

---

I tried modifying version in pacakage.json(by upgrading v0.0.9) at my pacakge, it worked.

but this method will confuse me in the future..

I searched like below.

`how to reset npm pack version`

`npm pack memorize version`

`npm pack revert`

but I couldn't find what I want.

is there anyone who can give me some keywords or sites for this problem?

Comment: Your question is a bit daunting. You'll have more responses if you can narrow down your question and make things more concise.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I added TLDR.